# application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions loading before viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, viewdidload

So I am writing an app that will read a JSON feed. In my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I am writing some code to download the JSON string and store it into a local NSString variable. I will then pass that string into ListingsViewController (which is the Root VC of the NavigationController). When I print out the JSON data in ListingsViewController, it is showing me (null) which is making me think that viewDidLoad is loading before - which seems illogical?

So here is my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Grab the feeds    
    NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.shoofeetv.com/iphonexml/view/all_channels.json"];
    NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];

    // Pass jsonData to the ListingsViewController
    ListingsViewController *listingsViewController = [[ListingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    listingsViewController.jsonData = jsonData;
    [listingsViewController release];

    // Display the navigation controller
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

My viewDidLoad method is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Listings";
    UIBarButtonItem *checkinButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Check In" 
                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                  target:self
                                  action:@selector(switchView)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = checkinButton;
    [checkinButton release];

   NSLog(@"%@", self.jsonData);

   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Please note that a common solution is to make sure that the App Delegate in MainWindow.xib must be connected to the File's Owner. Mine already is connected.

I will appreciate any help!

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Oh also, when I put two NSLogs in each function, the viewDidLoad NSLog appears first.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you are setting up a view controller with your code, but it is never shown within the navigation controller. you just set up a view controller, assign its jsonData a string and destroy the view controller immediately. I#m pretty sure the output you get is from a different view controller that you create in your main XIB.

what you want to do is create an empty navigation controller in your XIB and then do the following:

```
// Pass jsonData to the ListingsViewController
ListingsViewController *listingsViewController = [[ListingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListingsViewController" bundle:nil];
listingsViewController.jsonData = jsonData;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:listingsViewController animated:NO];
[listingsViewController release];

// Display the navigation controller
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

this will actually display the view controller you created.

Also remember that when you deploy your application, you need to load your json-data asynchronously and handle network errors (apple *will* test your app under various network conditions)

Comment: Thank you.. I'll try your suggestion now. Also, by "loading it asynchronously" you mean I need to use NSURLConnection to download the data and check that it downloaded?

Comment: Ok it kind of works now. The data is being passed to the view controller correctly now but I have a small problem. What I did was add "[self.navigationController pushViewController:listingsViewController animated:NO];" but now the problem is that it shows as a Back button on the top left "Root View Controller". I guess I didn't get the "create an empty navigation controller in your XIB" part. Could you please help me on this please?

Comment: Yes you'll have to do that. Or download and store locally and only check for updates - then you can use the local content when network is not available.

Comment: just try to find your view controller in interface builder and remove it (should be in the list view of the XIB contents). Alternatively, use `[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:listingsViewController] animated:NO]` to reset the whole navigation stack.

Comment: Thanks! I reset the whole nav stack and it worked. But I would just like to know why this Root View Controller button appeared in the first place.. Could you please explain that?

Comment: That is because you use a UINavigationController to manage your view controllers. it is responsible for the top navigation bar. the title is read from your ViewController's title property. when you push a new view controller with `animated:YES` you'll get this slide-in-effect automatically and the navigation controller will add a back button that will take you back to the previous navigation controller. i suggest you watch some iTunes U screencasts like http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/iphone-application-development/id384233225 (there are newer ones but this is very good)

Comment: you should watch track 14 (=Lecture 7) of that. they explain navigation and tab bar controllers there

Comment: Oh yeah right... yeah I already know all that. For some reason I just didn't think about it this time, I got confused. Thanks a lot Martin!